# How to make Arduino do High Speed I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c

I wired up two [MCP4725 DAC](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532229)'s to my Arduino and wrote a little demo sketch to test functionality. The sketch draws a Lissajous curve on my oscilloscope.
The output frequency is a bit disappointing (approx. 1.5kHz sample rate), but the datasheet to the DAC mentions High Speed I2C mode. Does Arduino (Mega1280) support High Speed I2C mode and if 'yes' how?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DAC0 ( 0xCC >> 1 )
#define DAC1 ( 0xCE >> 1 )

int sh[ 360 ] , sl[ 360 ];
int ch[ 360 ] , cl[ 360 ];

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  for ( int a = 0; a <= 360; a++ ) {
    int s = sin( a * 3.141592 / 180 ) * 2047 + 2048;
    int c = cos( a * 3.141592 / 180 ) * 2047 + 2048;
    sh[ a ] = int( s / 256 );
    sl[ a ] = s - sh[ a ] * 256;
    ch[ a ] = int( c / 256 );
    cl[ a ] = c - sh[ a ] * 256;
  }
}

void loop() {
  for ( int b = 0; b < 360; b++ ) {
      for ( int a = 0; a < 360; a += 6 ) {
      Wire.beginTransmission( DAC0 );
      Wire.send( ch[ a ] );
      Wire.send( cl[ a ] );
      Wire.endTransmission();
      Wire.beginTransmission( DAC1 );
      Wire.send( sh[ ( a * 2 + b ) % 360 ] );
      Wire.send( sl[ ( a * 2 + b ) % 360 ] );
      Wire.endTransmission();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick calculation (1.5[kS/s]×2[DAC's]×30[bits/frame]) gives 100kb/s, not even the 400kb/s I was expecting to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider going one level below the C++ object "Wire" and use their C files found here:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Wire/utility

There is a constant of interest in `twi.h`:

`#define TWI_FREQ 100000L`

And the register is set in the file `twi.c` like so:

```
// initialize twi prescaler and bit rate
  cbi(TWSR, TWPS0);
  cbi(TWSR, TWPS1);
  TWBR = ((F_CPU / TWI_FREQ) - 16) / 2;

/* twi bit rate formula from atmega128 manual pg 204
  SCL Frequency = CPU Clock Frequency / (16 + (2 * TWBR))
  note: TWBR should be 10 or higher for master mode
  It is 72 for a 16mhz Wiring board with 100kHz TWI */
```

Going by that comment, and without having to go into the datasheet (although I suggest that you do if you want to understand what those lines mean), it appears that the Arduino Mega (16 MHz) defaults to 100 kHz I2C clock.  Following the formula given, change the value of TWI_FREQ to achieve a desired I2C clock frequency.

However, after reading the datasheet of the Atmega, it appears to me that the fastest you can get [See edit].  Take a look at the section `24.5.2 Bit Rate Generator Unit` to confirm this.  If you define "High Speed" to be 3.4 MHz I2C, then **the answer appears to be no**, you can't achieve that with your current hardware, but you should be able to get something faster than the default 100 kHz if you really want to.

**EDIT:** It may be possible to achieve 1 MHz if I'm reading the datasheet correctly.  Formula used from the datasheet: SCL = (F_CPU)/(16 + 2*TWBR*4^TWPS)  The disclaimer below still stands :p

Disclaimer: I just took a quick glance at the docs to come up with the above, it's totally possible that I missed something. Please read the datasheet to confirm any of this and familiarize yourself with your microcontroller, since you are wanting to do something that the Arduino library does not offer.

Comment: ah ... the TWI_FREQ confirms my suspicion of 100kb/s bus speed.

Comment: Adding `TWBR = 10;` after `Wire.begin();` makes the bus run at 444kHz (the minimum according to the formula in your comment). Lower values work too (1 would be 888kHz), but I'll have to study the datasheet to verify your 250kHz statement.

Comment: @jippie, Please note that it's not *my* comment but one that I found in the underlying Arduino code - which I do not know if it's correct.  My 250 kHz estimate is based on the formula given in the datasheet, under section `24.5.2 Bit Rate Generator Unit`.  Can I ask how you're verifying the clock speed? With external tools physically or...?

Comment: Also note that the HS I2C protocol is little bit different. It requires a special 'start' byte that informs all slaves to go to HS I2C mode. The Atmega1280 doesn't have support for this, so if you want anything close to HS I2C you would need to bit-bang it. And I guess that may not be as fast as desired.

Comment: @jippie, slight edit

Comment: @Hans, thanks for that note, I didn't know that.

Comment: I verify the speed by measuring the width of the analog output steps on my oscilloscope. I have two DAC's and each one requires a frame of approx. 30bits. The numbers in my reply above came from the formula in the sniplet in your reply. 1MHz cannot be reached because setting TWBR to 0 works like setting it to 256.

Comment: @jippie, I understand that you want to measure the final speed at the DAC, but I think for the sake of this question (I2C related) it would be better to talk in terms of I2C speed, ie. measure of the I2C clock period.  Also, regarding your note, it would then be possible to achieve a max frequency of 667 kHz according to the datasheet?  If you can confirm this I'll update my answer.

Comment: Table 29-15 appears to preclude operation over 400kHz, at least officially.

Comment: I only have a conventional analog scope, measuring serial data / data rate with it is non trivial.

Comment: Bit clock peaks at 800kHz for TWBR=2. 1=>750k; 2=>800k; 3=>706k; 4=>714k; 5=>667k; 6=>645k; 7=>600k; 8=>500k 9=>465k; 10=>444k; 11=>421k. TWBR settings < 8 show a relatively much jitter.